# Is sending the value through POST for each input-change on a form wrong?

Tags: forms, post

I am developing a webshop, where it would be nice if the customer's input is not lost during the checkout process.
I am making a form, and to make sure the data is kept after a refresh, I now send the input-value through post at the onchange event. I store this in a session-object that represents the form. I use this object to fill the form on page-load/refresh.
This does result in a lot of post-requests, one for each input filled instead of just one for the whole form. I can imagine this would impact performance. Is this something I should worry about, and if so, how can I perform the same type of thing without all the requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends, if you expect enormous count of customers:)

Instead of posting after every change, you can also store these data in cookies on client side and ignore posting at all before complete submit. Or not post after each change but rather after some meaningfull timeout when some changes has been performed...

Comment: Setting a cookie would seem to be a better solution. Are there any negative consequences for this, like not having anough space for the cookie, or people having cookies turned off?

Comment: 1) how do you persist the session id at client side? is it in the cookie or in ugly url?
2) have you seen the lots of trash stored by google or any other site? I don't think, you'll be limited when storing some data from form...